# Not all query parameters appearing in return url

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, cookie-authentication

I have built a ASP.NET CORE MVC application and use cookie authentication. Below is my code in Startup.cs file.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // these must be set other ASP.NET Core will throw exception that no
    // default authentication scheme or default challenge scheme is set.
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
  .AddCookie(options =>
   {
       options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
   });
```

When the cookie expires, application redirects to the `/Account/Login` path with a Return Url containing the current url the user was in. This works fine until the current url has `0` or `1` query parameters. If the current url has 2 query paramaters then only the first query parameter is passed to the return URL. The Login method is as below.

```cs
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
   return View(new LogInViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
}
```

e.g.
If the current URL is `/Inspection?inspectionID=1&processTypeID=2` then the return url gets only `/Inspection?inspectionID=1`. The `processtypeID` parameter is not coming.

But when the browser is navigated to the `/Account/Login` URL when the cookie is expired, it shows the correct url `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/Inspection?inspectionID=1&processTypeID=2`

Can anyone point me why this is occurring and how to fix this?

Thanks,
Zehan

Comment: If "ReturnUrl" is a querystring, so what kind of "processTypeID" ?

Answer (score 1):

Encoding the the value of the redirect uri solved it for me.

In my case I had a blazor page with:

`<a href="auth/Signin?redirectUri=@RedirectUri">Sign In</a>`

where `RedirectUri` returns the full current page path, including multiple query parameters.

I changed the link to:

`<a href="auth/Signin?redirectUri=@UrlEncode(RedirectUri)">Sign In</a>`, the key being `UrlEncode(RedirectUri)`, which solved the problem for me.

`UrlEncode` can be found on the namespace `System.Web.HttpUtility`.